# What are some basic strategies for Labyrinth?

Tags: labyrinth

My comp sci class currently is on the topic of AIs and we're tasked to write an AI for Labyrinth (the Ravensburger game) and have them play each other to see who wrote the best AI. As someone who's never heard of the game or even touched before I can only think of a limited amount of strategy for the game. Can anyone who has played Labyrinth bestow some common and advanced strategies upon me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gotten to the point of always finding a way to reach the target in one move if one exists?

Comment: I didn't quite want to add my algorithm because a) my classmates are gonna probs find this when they google and b) it'd turn my post into a stackoverflow post :P 
Ill post it if you insist though

oh and c) my teacher's philosophy is that when you don't know how to solve a problem with code, ask a random stranger how they'd solve this problem

P.S. I am not sure what you're asking, is it in terms of code or thinking?

Comment: I'm trying to clarify what level of strategy you're looking for. It's unclear from your question what you actually know. A huge part of Labyrinth is being able to just get there in one move if possible, because you often can. If you can do that already, you need more advanced strategy. If you can't, then this is more of a "how do I write an algorithm" question and not so much a board games one.

Comment: Oh ok Ill edit my current thought into the main post

Answer (score 6):

A few tips:

- Static tiles are more stable (duh!), so going there is a bit more predictable. If you have goals on those, they have lower priority.
- Static tiles are more stable (again), so staying on a static tile at the end of your turn will assure you you are at the same place when you begin the next one.
- Manhattan distance (dx + dy) may be important because being close to a goal makes it easier to reach if you are not sure of what the board will look like on your next turn.
- Don't forget to use the "shortcut": if you stand at the edge of the board and you are pushed out, you teleport to the other side.
- Having a large reachable zone at the beginning of your turn allows you to adapt easily: if you can go to a lot of places, you can change your mind when trouble arrive.
- Play the anti-game. Even though I would never recommend that to any living player, as your goal here is clearly to win and not at all to have fun while doing it, crush your opponents completely without mercy! Sometimes, reaching your goal is more complicated that putting your opponent(s) in a tricky situation. Keep in mind who is about to win and don't be nice with him (or should I say "it"?) Everything that I said higher can be applied negatively to the others.